# Segmentation fault when passing a function as argument in a subroutine

Tags: fortran

I try to illustrate how to pass a function to a Newton Raphson procedure. I succeed with a very simple function (called `unefonction` see below) but it does not work with a function which has got parameters. This second fonction is called `gaussienne` and it takes one argument, x, and two optional arguments `mu` and `sig`. In my newton raphson procedure I called the fonction in this way : `f(x)`. What is strange for me is that during the execution, the program does as if the optional parameters `sig` and `mu` were present but they don't... Thus I do not understand ...

Here is the module which contains the functions

```
module fonction

  implicit none

  ! parametre pour la gaussienne
  double precision :: f_sigma = 1.d0, f_mu = 0.d0

  ! pi accessible uniquement en interne
  double precision, parameter :: pi = 3.14159265359d0

  contains

    double precision function unefonction(x)
        ! fonction : unefonction
        ! renvoie
        !    $\frac{e^x - 10}{x + 2}$

        implicit none

        ! arguments 
        double precision, intent(in) :: x

        unefonction = (exp(x) - 10.) / (x + 2.)

    end function unefonction

! * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 

    double precision function gaussienne(x, mu, sig)
        ! fonction gaussienne
        ! utilise les parametres definis dans le module si
        ! mu et sig ne sont pas passes en argument

        implicit none

        ! arguments
        double precision, intent(in)           :: x
        double precision, intent(in), optional :: mu, sig

        ! variables locales
        double precision :: norme, moy, sigma

        ! sigma
        if (present(sig)) then
            write(*,*)"sig present"
            sigma = sig
        else
            sigma = f_sigma
        end if

        ! mu
        if (present(mu)) then
            write(*,*)"mu present"
            moy = mu
        else
            moy = f_mu
        end if

        ! calcul de la gaussienne
        norme = 1.d0 / (sigma * sqrt(2.d0 * pi))
        gaussienne = norme * exp(-(x - moy)**2 / (2.d0 * sigma**2))

    end function gaussienne

end module fonction
```

Here is the module which contains the newton raphson procedure

```
module rechercheRacine

    implicit none

    contains

        subroutine newtonRaphson(racine, f, eps, cible)

            ! recherche l'antecedant de cible

            implicit none

            ! arguments
            double precision, intent(inout)        :: racine
            double precision, intent(in), optional :: cible, eps

            ! fonction dont on cherche la racine
            double precision, external :: f

            ! variables locales
            integer          :: compteur
            double precision :: xold, xnew, delta, valcible
            double precision :: threshold, fprim, fdex

            ! precision
            if (present(eps)) then
                threshold = eps
            else
                threshold = 1.d-10
            end if

            ! valeur cible
            if (present(cible)) then
                valcible = cible
            else
                valcible = 0.d0
            end if

            write(*,*) "--------------------------------------------------------"
            write(*,*) "                      NEWTON RAPHSON"
            write(*,*) "--------------------------------------------------------"
            write(*,"('x0    = ',e16.6)") racine
            write(*,"('seuil = ',e16.6)") threshold
            write(*,"('cible = ',e16.6)") valcible
            write(*,*) "--------------------------------------------------------"
            write(*,*) "                        ITERATIONS"
            write(*,*) "--------------------------------------------------------"

            ! initialisation
            compteur = 0
            delta    = 1.d0
            xold     = racine
            write(*, '(i4,4e16.6)') compteur, f(xold), xold, 0., threshold

            ! iterations
            do while (delta > threshold .and. compteur <= 100)

                ! calcul de la fonction en xold
                fdex = f(xold) - valcible

                ! calcul de la derivee numerique
                fprim  = (f(xold + threshold) - f(xold - threshold)) / (2.d0 * threshold) 

                ! application de l'iteration de Newton Raphson
                xnew = xold - fdex / fprim
                delta = abs(xnew - xold)
                compteur = compteur + 1

                ! affichage de la convergence
                write(*, '(i4,4e16.6)') compteur, fdex, xnew, delta, threshold

                ! mise a jour de xstart
                xold = xnew
            end do

            if (delta < threshold) then
                racine = xnew
                write(*, *) '--------------------------------------------------------'
                write(*, *) '                        CONVERGE'
                write(*, *) '--------------------------------------------------------'
                write(*, *) 'A la convergence demandee, une solution est:'
                write(*, "('x = ',e20.10,'    f(x) = ', e20.10)") racine, f(racine)
                write(*, *)
            else
                write(*, *) '--------------------------------------------------------'
                write(*, *) '                      NON CONVERGE'
                write(*, *) '--------------------------------------------------------'
            end if

        end subroutine newtonRaphson

end module rechercheRacine
```

Here is the main program :

```
program main

    ! contient la subroutine newtonRaphson
    use rechercheRacine

    ! contient la fonction
    use fonction

    implicit none

    double precision :: racine, eps, cible

    ! appel de la subroutine newtonRaphson
    ! sans la valeur cible : cible (defaut = 0)
    ! sans la precision : eps (defaut 1d-10)
    racine = 1.d0
    call newtonRaphson(racine, unefonction)

    ! --------------------------------------------------------

    ! appel de la subroutine newtonRaphson
    ! avec pour cible 10
    racine = 1.d0
    eps    = 1.d-14
    cible  = 10.d0
    call newtonRaphson(racine, unefonction, eps, cible)

    ! --------------------------------------------------------

    ! parametre de la gaussienne
    f_sigma = 2.d0
    f_mu = 5.d0
    ! appel de la subroutine newtonRaphson
    ! passage des arguments sous la forme clef = valeur
    cible = 0.1d0
    racine = 2.d0
    call newtonRaphson(cible = cible, f = gaussienne, racine = racine)

end program main
```

The main program works for the function called `unefonction` but it doesn't work for the `gaussienne` function.

Here is the error message :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F1B6F5890F7
#1  0x7F1B6F5896D4
#2  0x7F1B6EEEB49F
#3  0x4009D2 in __fonction_MOD_gaussienne at mod_fonction.f90:54
#4  0x40104D in __rechercheracine_MOD_newtonraphson at mod_racine.f90:59
#5  0x4016BA in MAIN__ at main.f90:40
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

I think that the `invalid memory reference` is due to the fact that the program does as if optional parameters `sig` and `mu` were present and thus looks for them  while they are not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that the function you pass indeed expects three arguments instead of one only. If you change the `external` declaration of `f` in the subroutine `newtonRaphson`

```
double precision, external :: f
```

to an explicit interface (which describes, how you really use it):

```
interface
  double precision function f(x)
    double precision, intent(in) :: x
  end function f
end interface
```

your code won't even compile due to the mismatch in the number of parameters.

They are different ways to pass "parameters" to the function `f` which is called from the routine `newtonRaphson`:

- You could expect `f` to have two `intent(in)` arguments instead of one: Additional to the value x, it could take also a real array, which may be of arbitrary size and may contain the necessary parameters. That would require following interface:

  ```
  interface
    double precision function f(x, params)
      double precision, intent(in) :: x
      double precision, intent(in) :: params(:)
    end function f
  end interface
  ```

  Those functions, which do not need parameters (like `unefonction`) would just not use   the content of the second parameter, while others (like `gaussienne`) would take their parameters from it.
- You could make `newtonRaphson` to expect a given extensible type (`class`) with a type bound procedure returning the value for a given x-value. You can then create abritrary extensions of this type, which may calculate the value for the given x-value based on some parameters stored as fields in the extended type. Then the program could look like below (I stripped several parts), but it would require Fortran 2003 compiler:

  ```
  module rechercheRacine
    implicit none

    type, abstract :: calculator
    contains
      procedure(getvalue_iface), deferred :: getvalue
    end type calculator

    interface
      double precision function getvalue_iface(self, x)
        import :: calculator
        class(calculator), intent(in) :: self
        double precision, intent(in) :: x
      end function getvalue_iface
    end interface

  contains

    subroutine newtonRaphson(racine, f, eps, cible)
      double precision, intent(inout)        :: racine
      class(calculator), intent(in)          :: f
      double precision, intent(in), optional :: cible, eps

      do while (delta > threshold .and. compteur <= 100)
        fdex = f%getvalue(xold) - valcible
        :
      end do

    end subroutine newtonRaphson

  end module rechercheRacine


  module fonction
    use rechercheRacine
    implicit none

    type, extends(calculator) :: unefonction
    contains
      procedure :: getvalue => unefonction_getvalue
    end type unefonction

    type, extends(calculator) :: gaussienne
      double precision :: mu = 0.0d0, sigma = 1.0d0
    contains
      procedure :: getvalue => gaussienne_getvalue
    end type gaussienne

  contains

    double precision function unefonction_getvalue(self, x)
      class(unefonction), intent(in) :: self
      double precision, intent(in) :: x
      unefonction_getvalue = (exp(x) - 10.) / (x + 2.)
    end function unefonction_getvalue

    double precision function gaussienne_getvalue(self, x)
      class(gaussienne), intent(in) :: self
      double precision, intent(in) :: x

      :
      gaussienne_getvalue = norme * exp(-(x - moy)**2 / (2.d0 * self%sigma**2))

    end function gaussienne_getvalue

  end module fonction


  program main
    use rechercheRacine
    use fonction
    implicit none

    type(unefonction) :: fone
    type(gaussienne) :: fgauss

    :
    call newtonRaphson(racine, fone)
    call newtonRaphson(cible = cible, f = fgauss, racine = racine)

  end program main
  ```

Comment: Nice answer. Actually, the external declaration was just a test that I forgave to delete. I thought that if a function/subroutine was in a module an explicit interface was automatically created. Am I wrong ? But I understand that the external declaration will remove the interface.
I thought that the optional declaration of the parameters sig and mu was the reason why I did not get error at the compilation.